# Understanding React useState() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I'm working on a functional React component using the `useState()` hook. I'm a little confused by either the way this hook should be used or the design decisions behind it.

I made a codepen example to illustrate my question:

https://codepen.io/svenvandescheur/pen/ewwBwR

**Class based component**

In a class based component, `this.setState({foo: 'bar'})` updated the state with only the keys in in the object passed to the first arguments. If the state already contained different values, those were left in place.

**Functional component**

I falsely assumed that the syntax and behavior of `setState()` provided by `useState()` would be very similar to its counterpart provided by `Component`. However, I noticed that `setState({foo: 'bar'})` would replace the entire state, removing keys that were not passed.

This issue can be addressed by passing the entire state on every call to `setState()` using a spread operator, then adding the the changes afterwards, like so: `setState({...state, foo: 'bar'})`.

This feels very repetitive, and in my real world scenario even caused a bug where new state was overriden with old state.

My question, is whether I'm understanding `useState()` from both `Component` as `useState()` correctly, and why this behavior was chosen. And what is the currently the preferred way of dealing with state in React.

Comment: the state updater also provides you with a callback just like `this.setState` 
 `useStateUpdater(prevState => ({ ...prevState, foo: 'bar' }))` to prevent overrides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. `setState` will merge current state and new state together to create a new state. `useState` will take the given value and replace old state.

This behaviour might seem unintuitive, but allows for primitive values to be used as state such as strings, numbers and booleans.

If you need more state you can simply add more `useState`'s. And if your state update logic becomes more than a little complex you should use `useReducer`.

Answer (score 0):

So if your state is an object, you'll want to create a new object and set with that. This may involve spreading the old state. For example:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState({ name: 'alice', age: 30 });

const onClick = () => {
  // Do this:
  setPerson(prevPerson => {
    return { 
      ...prevPerson, 
      age: prevPerson.age + 1 
    }
  })

}
```

That said, using hooks you often no longer need your state to be an object, and can instead use useState multiple times. If you're not using objects or arrays, then copying is not needed, so spreading is also not needed.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('alice');
const [age, setAge] = useState(30);

const onClick = () => {
  setAge(prevAge => prevAge + 1);
}
```